# Android NFC application crashes on enableForegroundDispatch

Tags: android, nfc

I try to create an application that reads the content and the ID of the tag. I have try to follow different tutorials, but all fails after I add the enableForegroundDispatch() to the onResume() function, I have also try to find answer here, but none of the answers helped on me.

The code:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.nfc.tech.Ndef;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static final String TAG = "NfcDemo";
public static final String MIME_TEXT_PLAIN = "text/plain";
private TextView mTextView, uid_text;
private NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data_text);
    uid_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.uid_text);
    mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

    if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
        // Stop here, we definitely need NFC
        Toast.makeText(this, "This device doesn't support NFC.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        return;

    }

    if (!mNfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        mTextView.setText("NFC is disabled.");
    } else {
        mTextView.setText("NFC ok!");
    }

   // handleIntent(getIntent());
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    /**
     * It's important, that the activity is in the foreground (resumed). Otherwise
     * an IllegalStateException is thrown. 
     */
    setupForegroundDispatch(this, mNfcAdapter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    /**
     * Call this before onPause, otherwise an IllegalArgumentException is thrown as well.
     */
    stopForegroundDispatch(this, mNfcAdapter);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) 
{ 
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {

        String type = intent.getType();
        if (MIME_TEXT_PLAIN.equals(type)) 
        {
            Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            byte[] uid = tag.getId();
            if (uid != null) 
            {
                uid_text.setText("ID: "+ByteArrayToHexString(uid));
            }
            new NdefReaderTask().execute(tag);

        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Wrong mime type: " + type);
        }
    }
    else 
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) 
    { 
        // In case we would still use the Tech Discovered Intent
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        String[] techList = tag.getTechList();
        String searchedTech = Ndef.class.getName();
        byte[] uid = tag.getId();
        if (uid != null) {
            uid_text.setText("ID: "+ByteArrayToHexString(uid));
        }
        /*
        for (String tech : techList) {
            if (searchedTech.equals(tech)) {
                new NdefReaderTask().execute(tag);
                break;
            }
        }*/
    }
}
private String ByteArrayToHexString(byte [] inarray)
{
    int i, j, in;
    String [] hex = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F"};
    String out= "";

    for(j = 0 ; j < inarray.length ; ++j) 
        {
        in = (int) inarray[j] & 0xff;
        i = (in >> 4) & 0x0f;
        out += hex[i];
        i = in & 0x0f;
        out += hex[i];
        }
    return out;
}
public static void setupForegroundDispatch(final Activity activity, NfcAdapter adapter) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), activity.getClass());
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(activity.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

    IntentFilter[] filters = new IntentFilter[1];
    String[][] techList = new String[][]{};

    // Notice that this is the same filter as in our manifest.
    filters[0] = new IntentFilter();
    filters[0].addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    filters[0].addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    try {
        filters[0].addDataType(MIME_TEXT_PLAIN);
    } catch (MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Check your mime type.");
    }

    adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(activity, pendingIntent, filters, techList);
}

public static void stopForegroundDispatch(final Activity activity, NfcAdapter adapter) {
    adapter.disableForegroundDispatch(activity);
}
private class NdefReaderTask extends AsyncTask<Tag, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Tag... params) {
        Tag tag = params[0];

        Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
        if (ndef == null) {
            // NDEF is not supported by this Tag. 
            return null;
        }

        NdefMessage ndefMessage = ndef.getCachedNdefMessage();

        NdefRecord[] records = ndefMessage.getRecords();
        for (NdefRecord ndefRecord : records) {
            if (ndefRecord.getTnf() == NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN && Arrays.equals(ndefRecord.getType(), NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT)) {
                try {
                    return readText(ndefRecord);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unsupported Encoding", e);
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
//functions to read data
    private String readText(NdefRecord record) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        /*
         * See NFC forum specification for "Text Record Type Definition" at 3.2.1 
         * 
         * http://www.nfc-forum.org/specs/
         * 
         * bit_7 defines encoding
         * bit_6 reserved for future use, must be 0
         * bit_5..0 length of IANA language code
         */

        byte[] payload = record.getPayload();
        byte[] uid = record.getId();
        // Get the Text Encoding
        String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16";

        // Get the Language Code
        int languageCodeLength = payload[0] & 0063;

        // String languageCode = new String(payload, 1, languageCodeLength, "US-ASCII");
        // e.g. "en"

        // Get the Text
        return new String(payload, languageCodeLength + 1, payload.length - languageCodeLength - 1, textEncoding);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
        if (result != null) {
            mTextView.setText("Read content: " + result);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What error do you get? Does your app crash? If yes, post the stack trace!

Comment: Now it works :D I have copied the full code and created the project from the beginning and it works without problems :$... Unfortunately I don't know what was the problem, maybe it is just android :/... C forever :D